# Prove x(t) is bounded given a integral inequality

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, inequality

I want to answer the following question:

$x=x(t)$ is defined and continuous on $[0,T)$ and satisfies an integral inequality

$$1 \leq x(t) \leq A_1 + A_2\int_0^t x(s)\big(1+\log x(s)\big) ds$$

for $0 \leq t < T$, where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are constants. Prove $x(t)$ is bounded on $[0,T]$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Boundedness of a function satisfying an inequality involving an integral of the function.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569598/boundedness-of-a-function-satisfying-an-inequality-involving-an-integral-of-the)

Comment: The solution provided in that post was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

We'll prove it without directly using the Gronwall's inequality.

By introducing $u(s):= \log(ex(s)),$ we see that $u$ satisfies

\begin{equation}
e \leq u(t) \leq eA_1 + A_2\int_0^t ue^u\,du =: v(t).
\end{equation}
Then, we observe $v'(t) = A_2 u(t)e^{u(t)}.$ Furthermore, since $t \mapsto te^t = \alpha(t)$ is strictly increasing on $t \geq 0,$ and $u \leq v,$ we see $ \alpha(u) \leq \alpha(v),$ or equivalently,

$$
A_2 \frac{ue^u}{ve^v} \leq A_2 \Leftrightarrow \frac{v'(t)}{ve^v} \leq A_2.
$$
Define $g(t) := \int_a^t \frac{\,dt}{te^t},$ where $a>0$ is any real number.

Then we see, 
$$
\frac{\,dg(v)}{\,dx} \leq A_2,
$$
and hence integrating, we see with $k = v(a),$ 
$$
g(v(t)) \leq  g(k) + A_2(t-a).
$$
Since $g$ is increasing, we see
$$
v(t) \leq g^{-1} \left( g(k) + A_2(t-a) \right),
$$
and we are done if we by recalling that $y(t) \leq v(t),$ except a remark in order, namely that the above estimate doesn't depend on the choice of $a.$ Indeed, 
setting $\tilde{g(t)} = \int_{\tilde a}^t \frac{\,dt}{\alpha(t)},$ we see
$
\tilde{g(v)} = g(v) - \int_a^{\tilde{a}} \frac{\,dt}{\alpha(t)},
$
and $\tilde{g}^{-1}(v) = g^{-1}(v + \int_a^{\tilde{a}} \frac{\,dt}{\alpha(t)}).$

Comment: As the other posted answer's comments indicate, it seems unclear how Gronwall's gives the result.  Would you care to explain any of the particulars?